How can I pass different viewModels in a .navigationDestination in SwiftUI
I Have a SwiftUI View called MessageListView Which represents a chat window between two users when a user press on the other user name I want to navigate to the other user profile screen from the MessageListView.
What is confusing to me is how am I supposed to pass parameters like ViewModels into the views while navigating from different levels in the navigation stack, I made a MessageListViewFactory class which handles the creation of the views but in this way I will be only able to append paths using the navigator for example navigator.navigateToProfileItemView() how can I navigate to views while being able to inject viewModels that depends on values deep down the stack view ?
Here is a sample code of my implementation.
struct MessageListView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel : MessageListViewModel
    @StateObject var navigator = MessageListFlow.shared
    
    init(viewModel: MessageListViewModel,otherProfile: Binding<Int?>) {
        _viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: viewModel)
        _otherProfile = otherProfile
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $navigator.path) {
           VStack {
           Text("otherUserProfile")
           .onTapGesture { 
           navigator.navigateToProfileItemView()
           }
        }.navigationDestination(for: MessageListNavigation.self, destination: { destination in
                MessageListViewFactory.setViewForDestination(destination)
        })
      }
    }
}

enum MessageListNavigation {
    
    case messageInfoView
    case profileSelectionView
    case fileMessageViewer
    case profileMainView
    case videoMessageViewer
    case groupInfoView
    case fileCarouselView
    case reportChatView
    case reportChatSubmitView
    case addPeopleToGroup
    case createUpdateGroupView
    case locationMessageSelectionView
    case messageList
    case forwardMessageView
    
}

class MessageListFlow: ObservableObject {
    
    static let shared = MessageListFlow()
    
    @Published var path = NavigationPath()

    func clear() {
        path = .init()
    }
    
    func navigateBackToRoot() {
        path.removeLast(path.count)
    }
    
    func backToPrevious() {
        path.removeLast()
    }
    
    func navigateToMessageInfoView(){
        path.append(MessageListNavigation.messageInfoView)
    }
    
    func navigateToProfileSelectionView() {
        path.append(MessageListNavigation.profileSelectionView)
    }
    
    func navigateToFileMessageViewer() {
        path.append(MessageListNavigation.fileMessageViewer)
    }
    
    func navigateToProfileItemView()  {
        path.append(MessageListNavigation.profileMainView)
    }
    
    func navigateToVideoMessageViewer() {
        path.append(MessageListNavigation.videoMessageViewer)
    }
    
    func navigateToGroupInfoView() {
        path.append(MessageListNavigation.groupInfoView)
    }
    
    func navigateToFileCarouselView()  {
        path.append(MessageListNavigation.fileCarouselView)
    }
    
    func navigateToReportChatView() {
        path.append(MessageListNavigation.reportChatView)
    }
    
    func navigateToReportChatSubmitView() {
        path.append(MessageListNavigation.reportChatSubmitView)
    }
    
    func navigateToAddPeopleToGroupView() {
        path.append(MessageListNavigation.addPeopleToGroup)
    }
    
    func navigateToCreateUpdateGroupInfoView() {
        path.append(MessageListNavigation.createUpdateGroupView)
    }
    
    func navigateToLocationMessageSelectionView() {
        path.append(MessageListNavigation.locationMessageSelectionView)
    }
    
    func navigateToMessageList() {
        path.append(MessageListNavigation.messageList)
    }

    func navigateToForwardMessageView() {
        path.append(MessageListNavigation.forwardMessageView)
    }

    func done() {
        path = .init()
    }
}


class MessageListViewFactory {
    
    static func setViewForDestination(_ destination: MessageListNavigation) -> AnyView {
        
        switch destination {
        case .messageInfoView:
            AnyView(Text("messageInfoView"))
        case .profileSelectionView:
            AnyView(Text("profileSelectionView"))
        case .fileMessageViewer:
            AnyView(Text("fileMessageViewer"))
        case .profileMainView:
            AnyView(Text("profileMainView"))
        case .videoMessageViewer:
            AnyView(Text("videoMessageViewer"))
        case .groupInfoView:
            AnyView(Text("groupInfoView"))
        case .fileCarouselView:
            AnyView(Text("fileCarouselView"))
        case .reportChatView:
            AnyView(Text("reportChatView"))
        case .reportChatSubmitView:
            AnyView(Text("reportChatSubmitView"))
        case .addPeopleToGroup:
            AnyView(Text("addPeopleToGroup"))
        case .createUpdateGroupView:
            AnyView(Text("createUpdateGroupView"))
        case .locationMessageSelectionView:
            AnyView(Text("locationMessageSelectionView"))
        case .messageList:
            AnyView(Text("messageList"))
        case .forwardMessageView:
            AnyView(Text("forwardMessageView"))
        }
    }
}

I have tried to use associated values to pass view models along with enum cases but that didn't work as the enum must conform to hashable protocol.

Hint: SwiftUI views are not views. So, this enables you to give a SwiftUI view the role to instantiate a view model with configuration values (aka dependencies) provided by a parent view which itself has extracted it from the SwiftUI environment, which itself has a parent view which received the parameters the view model needs to work with (for example some Entity ID). Return this view in the body of the navigationDestination modifier.
The innermost view - holding the view model - publishes the view state and handles user intents to/from the content view (child view).

It's better to use the View structs as the view model. StateObject is for something else.

You should look at some basic SwiftUI tutorials, you have a lot of fundamental errors in your code. StateObject should always be private, using a singleton with a StateObject is a contradiction that can cause memory leaks. the navigationDestination should be inside the NavigationStack, AnyView is highly discouraged.
